# how to check if two lists are equal, up to a permutation in caml

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone i'am beginner in caml and i was trying to answer the question below but i don't know from where to start: can someone help me please to solve this?

Write a function :a list -> a list -> bool that check if two lists are equivalent up to permutation. For example [2; 3; 4; 3] is equivalent to [3; 3; 4; 2] but not equivalent to [2; 4; 3]. So how can we check if two lists are equal, up to a permutation in caml?

Comment: If you're using caml what does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: I think it does not have anything to do with specific language.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I would say just sort the arrays and loop through them by checking one by one. You may also check the equivalence of length. If the length of arrays are different then no need to execute extra code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I do not know javascript or caml very well. Here is my version. Java is high-level enough, and I'm sure you will figure it.
Here is how I'd do it:

```
boolean equals(Type A1[], Type A2[])
{
    int len1 = A1.length; // length of the first array
    int len2 = A2.length; // length of the second array

    // if the length are not equal
    if(len1 != len2){
        return false;
    }
    /*sort algorithm of your choice */
    sort(A1); // sort first array  
    sort(A2);

    for(int i = 0; i < len1; i++){
        if(A1[i] != A2[i]) // if there is at least one non equal element
            return false;
    }

    // everything is ok
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple option to compare array. One easy way would be make a string.

```js
let arr1 = [2, 3, 4, 3].sort()
let arr2 = [3, 3, 4, 2].sort()
let arr3 = [2, 4, 3].sort()

if(JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2)) {
  console.log('arr1 = arr2');
}

if(JSON.stringify(arr1) !== JSON.stringify(arr3)) {
  console.log('arr1 != arr3');
}
```